# looping over char with while loop in c

Tags: arrays, c, linux, char

In my program, I require the user to input a sequence of numbers with spaces. Here is the code I have implemented:

```c
    char cinput, c = ' ';
    Printf("type numbers:\n");
    scanf("%c", &cinput);
    const char *input;
    input = &cinput;
    int length = strlen(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }
```

Assuming that my input is `1 2 3`, I am unable to obtain the value `2` when attempting to print `input[1]`. It is important to note that I am unaware of the total number of numbers in the sequence so I can not define an array.

I would appreciate it if there is a method to read a character sequence using a `while` loop.

Please take note that the program must be written exclusively in the C programming language.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You read only one single character, there's nothing to loop over. Are you trying to read a *string*? Perhaps you should use `fgets` to read the whole line?

Comment: And I feel that you need to refresh your beginners material when it comes to input and strings.

Comment: @s3dev — the `%c` conversion specification reads one byte, regardless of whether it is a space.  It doesn't skip leading white space, unlike almost every other conversion specification.  The other exceptions are `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.

Comment: You have not allocated space to store a string. You have not allocated space to store the null byte at the end of a string.  There are lots of problems with this code because of the lack of allocated space.

Comment: Your code does not even compile

Answer (score 1):

Before my sleeping pill taks hold, I'll show you what you should do:

```
char input[256];  // An array of multiple characters

// Read one whole line of input, including the ending newline
// Will not read more than 255 characters though
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error reading the input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Now we have a null-terminated sequence of characters in
// the array input.

// Loop over the array, one character at a time, until we get to the end
// (the end is when there's the null-terminator character)
for (size_t i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    // If the current character is a space (space, tab, newline, etc.)
    // then skip it by continuing the loop with the next character
    if (isspace(input[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Here we have a non-space character at index i, print it
    printf("input[%d] = '%c'\n", i, input[i]);
}
```

The comments should hopefully be enough to explain what each part of the code is doing.

Note that the loop checks for the string null-terminator, not the newline. That's because if the input is longer than 255 characters then the newline will not be present. The null-terminator will *always* be present in the string. That's kind of what makes it a string.

Also note that there's no need to be cheap with the space for the input string. Don't limit to ten or so characters, that's just no need to do that. Keep it long enough to handle most normal input, and then some more. If there is a requirement to be able to handle longer lines (and remember, `fgets` reads only one line at a time) then you need a more complex solution to read the input. But for most normal cases, the code shown above is Good Enough™.

---

References:

- [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)
- [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit)
- [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status)
- [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements of "a number with spaces" suggest a simpler solution. `scanf` allows you to directly parse a number using the expected format string, on-line, without reading it into a temporary buffer and without conversion from a character.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    int number, accum = 0;
    int convert;
    errno = 0; // want to check for errors
    printf("type numbers:\n");
    while((convert = scanf(" %d", &number)) != EOF) { // there is input
        if(convert != 1) { // valid conversion; is important to check
            fprintf(stderr, "matching failure\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        accum += number; // for example...
    }
    if(errno) { // scanf == EOF; it has closed normally, or error?
        perror("input");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("total: %d\n", accum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From [scanf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace()) are skipped

Hence, this can not differentiate between white-space. Usually press Ctrl-d to close `stdin`. This does not behave in the way that `fgets` does, because `'\n'` is `isspace` and will just skip it.

> `%d` Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of strtol() with the value 10 for the base argument. In the absence of a size modifier, the corresponding argument must be a pointer to int.

Or similar (`%u`, `%i`, `%e`, `%f`, `%g`). Note that this doesn't do exceptional situations very well, if you want this, suggest spiting it, (*eg* [fgets](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html), [strtol](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strtol.html).)

> If a read error occurs the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

You really should check, but this probably is overkill for an assignment.

If you want to store that number, that is another thing. (How many numbers?)